# Centering two titles next to each other

Tags: html, css

So I've been struggling with this for some while and the motive is just to learn but I simply want to center two `<h2>` titles next to each other. Preferably wrapping them in some sort of a container so that I simply can apply `margin: 0 auto;` Like:

```
<div>
  <h2>Hello!</h2>
  <h2>Hello!</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: I believe `h2` have `display:block` by default so changing it to `display:inline-block` might just do it

Comment: Why can't you do `<h2>Hello! Hello!</h2>`?

Comment: @BSMP but that still would not center the titles!?

Comment: @ochi - If there's only one `h2` tag then you can center the text like normal. The tricky thing here isn't figuring out how to center text, it's getting two elements that are normally block level elements next to each other. I'm just curious why the OP needs the text in separate tags since the text needs to be on the same line anyway.

Comment: @BSMP you asked a fair question (and why I up-voted it) but the OP's question was also about centering both titles next to each other (and why I commented) so simply combining the `h2`s would only accomplish half of the desired output - but you already know that.  It's merely for others following up the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little different approach than Xahed, but working just as good
DEMO HERE:
http://jsfiddle.net/s0y9pg0L/

```
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:250px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.centered-text {
   text-align: center;   
}

h2 {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

with HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="centered-text">
        <h2>Hello!</h2>
        <h2>Hello!</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is a little more proof if you're actually gonna use it in a website.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. You are great!

Answer (score 4):

Here, check the snippet. You'll get both h2 centered.

```css
.container{
  text-align:center;
}

h2{
  text-align:left;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>Hello!</h2>
  <h2>Hello!</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest version I can think of is, very similar to the other ones posted (sorry).

If you do not want to affect all other `h2`s in the page, give the specific ones a class

```css
h2{
  display: inline-block;
}

.wrapper{
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h2>Hello!</h2>
  <h2>Hello!</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here, I hope this helps. I think this is what you meant by center two h2 titles next to each other.

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0 auto
}
#title1 {
  float:left;
  width: 249px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
#title2 {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 249px;
  text-align: center;

}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="title1"><h2>Hello!</h2></div>
  <div id="title2"><h2>Hello!</h2></div>
</div>
```